# Как перебрать массив в случайном порядке?

Tags: java, массивы, коллекции, случайные-числа

У меня есть некоторый массив. Мне нужно перебрать его в случайном порядке циклом (но чтобы каждый элемент массива был вызван один раз) или отсортировать случайным образом исходный массив. То есть у меня есть, к примеру, массив "один", "два", "три", а мне нужно вывести его случайным образом, например, "два", "один", "три". Если для массивов такого нет, но есть для коллекции, то тоже подойдёт. Хочется не набирать всё вручную и не изобретать велосипед.

Comment: См. тасование (shuffle) Фишера-Йетса. [Пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1520212/844416)

Comment: Collections.shuffle(list); - есть такой метод для коллекций. Превратить массив в лист не составляет труда. Собственно, и все...

Answer (score 4):

Или так:

```
String[] a = {"a", "b", "c"};
List<String> v = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(a));
Collections.shuffle(v);
for (String s : v) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Например, можно так:

```
Integer[] m = new Integer[]{3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 7, 91};

Arrays.asList(m).stream().sorted(new Comparator<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        return new Random().nextInt();
    }
}).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Как указано в комментариях ниже - это не самый лучший вариант. Используйте `shuffle` как указано в других ответах.

Comment: такое ощущение что нестандартные методы сортировки могут зациклиться при таком подходе, но я не уверен

Comment: да shuffle лучше использовать

Comment: Ваша реализация компаратора нарушает требования. Это может привести к исключению.

Answer (score 0):

Пара способов использования побочных эффектов от многопоточности:

```
// проще всего: выведет числа от 0 до 20 в случайном порядке
IntStream.range(0, 20).parallel().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Если массив уже есть:

```
// unboxed
int[] arr1 = {3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 7, 91};
Arrays.stream(arr1).parallel().forEach(System.out::println);

// boxed
Integer[] arr2 = {3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 7, 91};
Stream.of(arr2).parallel().forEach(System.out::println);

// строковый массив (то же самое)
String[] arr3 = new String[] {"один", "два", "три", "четыре", "много"};
Stream.of(arr3).parallel().forEach(System.out::println);
```